# ¿OnMapClickListener para un website?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

He investigado un poco acerca de este tema y me pregunto si hay una forma de hacer que al hacer `click` en un mapa de Google maps en mi sitio web yo pueda obtener la los valores LatLng (latitud y longitud) del punto en donde se ha hecho click.

Sé que esto se puede hacer en android mediante `OnMapClickListener` que me devuelve esos datos. Pero no encuentro una forma de hacer algo parecido pero en mi sitio web.

Estos valores los pretendo usar para crear mapas estáticos, en el cual se dibuje la ruta entre dos puntos uno ya predeterminado y otro que obtiene mediante una dirección escrita, algo como "New york estados unidos". Pero en el país donde vivo estas direcciones fallan mucho por lo que necesito que a veces colocar manualmente esos datos *LatLng* asi que para hacer el proceso mas fácil para mi cliente que solo baste hacer `click` en el lugar y automáticamente se rellene la información de latlng

EDIT: El sitio esta hecho basicamente en php, usando laravel he investigado en la documentación de la API de google maps pero solo veo ese comando y es para Android

Comment: La pregunta no menciona [tag:php], pero si menciona a [tag:google-maps], tampoco se menciona los buscado/investigado sobre el tema, como por ejemplo si has buscado en este sitio o en el sitio de la documentación oficial.

Comment: Así? La verdad no encontré mucho, solo ese comando y solo funciona en android. Pero la idea es que funcione como eso usando Javascript

Comment: Mejor. Yo habría incluído el enlace a la documentación revisada para mayor precisión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es muy posible que a la hora de buscar documentación no la hayas ido a buscar al sitio adecuado. Por lo que puedo entrever has estado buscando en la API de Android en lugar de en la [API Web de JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=es-419) que me parece entender que es lo que necesitas.

El objeto mapa dispone de un evento `click` que puedes usar y en la información del evento, tenemos el objeto LatLng de la posición en donde hemos marcado. Lo único que necesitas hacer es suscribirte a dicho evento:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   alert(event.latLng);
});
```

En la documentación de la clase `Map` vemos una lista de eventos a los que podemos asociar un *listener* entre los que se encuentra el evento `click`:

Documentación oficial:

> This event is fired when the user clicks on the map. An ApiMouseEvent
>   with properties for the clicked location is returned unless a place
>   icon was clicked, in which case an IconMouseEvent with a placeid is
>   returned. IconMouseEvent and ApiMouseEvent are identical, except that
>   IconMouseEvent has the placeid field. The event can always be treated
>   as an ApiMouseEvent when the placeid is not important. The click event
>   is not fired if a marker or infowindow was clicked.

---

Traducción casera:

> Este evento se lanza cuando el usuario hace click en el mapa. Se
>   devuelve un `ApiMouseEvent` con las propiedades para la ubicación
>   donde se ha hecho click a menos que se haya hecho click sobre un icono
>   de "lugar", en ese caso, se devuelve un `IconMouseEvent` con un
>   `placeid`. `IconMouseEvent` y `ApiMouseEvent` son identicos, a
>   excepción the que `IconMouseEvent` contiene el campo `placeid`. El
>   evento siempre se puede tratar como si fuera un `ApiMouseEvent` en
>   caso de que el `placeid` no sea importante. El evento click no se
>   lanza si se hace click sobre un `marker` o un `infowindow`.

Comment: Es correcto amigo, no había visto esta parte de la documentación. Descuido mio tal vez, peor me has ayudado bastante! Muchas gracias!